# Single user not able to connect to OOF URL on Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I was recently asked to setup an Automatic Reply(Out of Office) message for a user that recently left the company I work at. All users log into Terminal Servers to do their work and as such, to access their emails. After failing to set it using the "Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration" command on the Exchange Shell, I had to get into the user's profile manually by resetting their password via Active Directory. In Outlook 2010 the "Automatic Replies" displayed the following:

*Your Out of Office settings cannot be displayed, because the server is currently unavailable. Try again later.*

Testing if AutoDiscover has been configured was successful. 
The only thing I can try next is correcting the OOF URL, but every other user can set Automatic Replies of their own and are connected to the same Exchange server. Only one user can't connect it seems. Is there anything else I could be missing since its only a single user being affected?

Answer (score 0):

According your description, it seems only happen on special account.

If you try on another machine, could it be successful?

Sometimes, you could first try to delete all windows credentials and retry the OOF rule.

Next, check the OOF URL, it should be same as EWS URL, such as: https://exserver.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Try to access this URL in browser, type credential if it prompts. Make sure you can access the page.

In another way, you could try to move the problematic user to another database to see if it works.

Comment: Tried it on another machine, but to no avail. I did check the OOF URL on a few of the browsers but I end up getting a web page error stating: 
"There is a problem with this website’s security certificate. The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address." I assume this isn't normal.
I'll try moving the user to another database and see if the automatic replies work after that.